# Best practice on running a package installer inside Docker with a private repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose, repository, private

Running commands locally with private repositories is trivial and that part is fine.

What I'm trying to do is to ensure Docker is used via a Makefile as a standards piece around running projects.

I am currently trying to get Docker to install packages that are private. There is no option for a VPN and hosting our own git service like gitlab or bitbucket which give the issue of not being able to install private packages within Docker compose.

There are two ways around this I have come across and got working successfully:

1. Copy my SSH Key over to the box and get it running internally to that container
2. Copy over the auth.json/.npmrc and so on to the container

Both of these come with issues:

1. If someone shares the container or pushes to the package repository then their SSH key is potentially compromised and will need to reset and possibly update any servers/services they use to access
2. The auth.json/.npmrc files are lesser a risk as the auth token can be scoped to read only and easily re-generated without a massive impact

I'm looking at PHP Composer as a working example at the moment where my docker compose file looks like this:

```yaml
version: "2.0"

services:
  composer:
    image: composer
    volumes:
      - ./.composer/auth.json:/tmp/auth.json
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app

  php:
    image: php:7.2-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
       - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
```

This works fine, but need to add something to remove that auth.json post command like `docker-compose run --rm composer install`. Is it possible to run a "post_run" type command in docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently setup private packagist which solves one of the issues you've described.

Using a token that is passed as a private variable on the CI and everyone on the team has their individual token they can use too.